# Programmatically find out field name of an Id-field

Tags: entities

Depending on the type of entity, it is either nid/vid/uid and possibly other. It is nice to have an `->id()` method which allows you to work with data in an uniform fashion without relying on those details, but there are quite some use-cases, where I am running into troubles.

Just an example, getting list of revision ids for an generic entity seems not possible without knowing the name of the id-field.

```php
$entityTypeId = $entity->getEntityTypeId();
$entityId = $entity->id();

$typeStorage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage($entityTypeId);

$query = $typeStorage->getQuery();
$query->allRevisions();
$query->condition("??????", $entityId);
```

Comment: Can't test it at the moment but try `$id_field = $entity->getKey('id');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EntityType provides a function to get field keys: `EntityType::getKeys`. The result is an array and the `id` key identifies the property name of the primary field.

See https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityType.php/function/EntityType%3A%3AgetKeys